# python unittest.mock assert no properties attributes methods accessed

Tags: python, mocking, python-unittest

How can I assert that a mock object was untouched? e.g. Assert no properties were accessed, no methods called, no attributes read or modified?

Is the simple answer "user a regular Mock and not a MagicMock"? If so, how to combine that with `unittest.mock.patch`?

Comment: If you use `None` instead of a mock, all you need to do is verify that no `AttributeError` is raised.

Comment: @chepner that could be clever; I suspect it could be used with patch like `unittest.mock.patch('target', new=type(None))`